# copy / create multiple files

Tags: powershell, file-io, powershell-3.0

I need to first create and then copy some hundreds of folders & files via powershell (first create them on a local store and then copy them to a remote store).
However, when my foreach loop runs, every 40 or so write attempt fails due to "another process" which blocks the file/folder. 
I currently fixed the issue using a simple sleep between every file creation (100ms). However, I wonder if there is no better way to do this? Especially when copying multiple files the sleep would depend on the network latency and dosn't seem to be a good solution to me.

Is there a way to "wait" till the write-operation of a file completed before starting another operation? Or to check if a file is still blocked by one process and wait till it's free again?

Comment: How are you creating the files?  Are you using a .NET Stream or StreamWriter object that needs to be disposed?

Comment: i'm using plain simple `Set-Content`

Comment: Bummer then Set-Content should be taking care of closing files it creates.  Is it possible you have some AV software that is scanning the files right after you create them?  BTW if you're using Set-Content then that command won't complete until it is finished so no "wait" should be necessary.

Comment: yeh, that's what it should be like. However, I will try to trace down the specific PID of the process that's blocking and report back.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the error anymore. Dunno why, but suddenly it works even without any sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your code as a job? Example:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
     #operation here..
    } | Wait-Job
    #Log result of job using ex. $job and:  '$job | Receive-Job'   to get output
}
```

You could also extend it to create multiple jobs, and then use `Get-Job | Wait-Job` to wait for the all to finish before you proceed.

Comment: I have been thinking about it but then rejected because IMO it's a work-around and no solution. I can't belive it's not possible to fail-safe batch copy some files in 2012.

Comment: it is. using 3rd party copy/synch software that's supposed to do this. but what fails exactly, creating the file or reading it(copy to remote place)? if it's after the file is created, it's probably AntiVirus. To test that, disable real-time detection (at least exclude the folder you save files in) and try again.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the error anymore. Dunno why, but suddenly it works even without any sleep.

Comment: well, thats nice. if it comes back, try excluding the folder fra AV. I'm also guessing(don't know) that set-content throws out an exception when this write access error occours, so you could modify your script with a try/catch to pickup the exception, sleep 100ms and try again. then it would just sleep when it needed to.

Comment: well, the try catch thing sounds like a good idea. I'll implement it just in case...